# Password validation Regular expression

Tags: regex, passwords

I have a password validation like the following rules

1. Should contains at most 15 chars and 8 chars at least
2. Password should contain 2 numeral character
3. There is no importance where to put the two numeral chars in start or end even if they anywhere in the password

Comment: `password12` yay! it works. By which I mean that your criteria do not discriminate good passwords from bad ones and all you'll do is annoy your users.

Comment: I encourage you to rethink this solution. Why give artificial limits to what a password can be? Let the user decide how strong their password is without imposing artificial constraints on them.

Comment: here is my regx 70% works correctly
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])$/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
^(?=\D*\d\D*\d).{8,15}$
```

Comment: Won't this fail to find alpha chars at the end?

Comment: I should have said non-numeric. The way your regex is written doesn't it have to end with a \d (numeric) char?

Comment: ＠Rob: No. Do you know what's a lookahead assertion?

Answer (score 5):

The best you can do is present your user with an estimate of the strength of their password and let them shoot their own foot if they wish.

Any scheme to force people to make good passwords is doomed by the ability of people to use post-it notes.