# Regex for password policy

Tags: regex, passwords

I need to enforce the following password policy :

> at least 9 characters, with at least one character from each of the 4
>   character classes (alphabetic lower and upper case; numeric, symbols).

Any regex experts can help out here ? (I am using a Java regex engine)

While we're at it, is there any online tool that can generate a regex for these kind of tasks ?

Thanks !

Comment: A good reference for regex is at http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html. Please post the reg ex that you've tried already

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387785/password-validation-regular-expression

Comment: @FelixKling nothing is wrong with it, but there are so many other stuff i want to learn first ;)

Comment: Don't! This has been answered so many times on SO, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3466868/297323 Break it up into different function, where each performs one single check. This approach is future-proof and above all it's maintainable.

Comment: alright, learned my lesson. thanks for the links, it will start investigating.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(?=.{9,})(?=.*?[^\w\s])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*?[a-z].*
```

Note that this pattern doesn't include special utf chars like `ö`. I would not do this in one regex. I would split it and search for each thing, if you want to validate it.

Comment: if you are in javascript land and using jquery I'd recommend jquery validation plugin, here's a strong password gist https://gist.github.com/mrgcohen/9806928

Comment: @mc if you validate data only on js-side of an app, you have no security at all. The server validation has to be performed regardless.

Comment: @Dariusz agreed, however it's nice to have things happen client side too so they are pretty :)  - if you wanted you could try to save and run validation on the backend (remotely). But it's nice validating before it hits your machine (if possible).

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I would do it (using positive lookahead):

```
(?=.{9,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\p{Punct}).*
```

Full example and test:

```
                       //    Regexp                Description
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=.{9,})"   +     // "" followed by 9+ symbols
                            "(?=.*[a-z])" +     // --- ' ' --- at least 1 lower
                            "(?=.*[A-Z])" +     // --- ' ' --- at least 1 upper
                            "(?=.*[0-9])" +     // --- ' ' --- at least 1 digit
                            "(?=.*\\p{Punct})"+ // --- ' ' --- at least 1 symbol
                            ".*");              // the actual characters
String[] tests = {
        "aB99",         // too short
        "abcdefghijk",  // missing A
        "abcdefGHIJK",  // missing 5
        "12345678910",  // missing a
        "abcDEF12345",  // missing punct
        "abcDEF-2345"   // works!
};

for (String s : tests) {
    boolean matches = p.matcher(s).matches();
    System.out.printf("%-12s: %b%n", s, matches);
}
```

**Output:**

```
aB99        : false
abcdefghijk : false
abcdefGHIJK : false
12345678910 : false
abcDEF12345 : false
abcDEF-2345 : true
```

---

**Final remark:** The problem with this approach is that it's not very user friendly. If you are to give a sensible response to a user, such as "*The password is missing a digit-symbol*" you need to do the work again (to figure out which requirement failed).

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple regexp's to solve this:

9 chars - you can regexp this but .length() >= 9 is much better!

For the character classes you should use one pr class:

```
[a-z]+
[A-Z]+
[0-9]+
[£$%&{[...]+ //all the possible symbols you want to accept
or perhaps: 
[:punct:]+ // this depends on your programming language..
or like in the suggestion by @david-halter:
[^\w\s]+  // not alphanumeric or spaces
```