# Python regex if match for more than one criteria in the same regex string

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I am currently learning python and do some excercices and have the following problem. I take user input for Password which should be at least 8 chars long, have capital letter, small letter and a special char.

What I would like to understand is, can I combine all of the above in one regex as below, or I need to list each and every case separately (see below).

Using only one:

```
whole_check = re.compile(r'''(
                            [A-Z]    #Check for capital letter
                             \d       #Check for number
                             \W       #check for special character)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

So how can I do a multiple if match here. As example:

```
if not [A-Z]:
    do something
if not \d:
    do something
```

The only other option is if i define each category in a separate variable:

```
cap_letter = re.compile(r'[A-Z]')
small_letter = re.compile(r'[a-z]')
```

Thanks for clearing this for me.

Answer (score 0):

See [Regex for password policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921933/regex-for-password-policy). Generally the answer is: yes, you could put it into one regex, but you should consider not doing that, as it will be much easier to maintain and read/understand in a week if you don't do that :)

Comment: So seems the multiple one is the go to, as with the one liner I cannot exactly tell which one failed. Good to know. Thanks!